.htaccess to accept parameters in URL
I have a page in Wordpress with the following structure website.com.au/pre-registration/parameter-name/, where the parameter name was originally a GET parameter but I was requested to make it part of the URL.
How do I make my .htaccess understand that he must disregard the last part and led the user to website.com.au/pre-registration instead of returning a 404?
Tried many possibilities I found on web, but none worked.
Edit: My htaccess looks like this at the moment:
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

